# Enviar a usuario a las configuraciones del dispositivo por medio de un boton android studio

Tags: android-studio, botón, android-intent

Hola quisiera saber si hay alguna forma en la que por medio de un botón en mi aplicación el usuario pueda acceder a las configuraciones de su dispositivo movil. Tengo entendido que este tipo de acciones se realizan por medio de itent implícito, pero no encuentro la instrucción para realizar la acción que deseo. ¿Es posible, o se hace uso de algún otro método ?

```
 btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_XXXXX);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Debería ser algo como esto: `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);`

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona correctamente, ¿sabes en que parte de la documentación puedo encontrar mas relacionado con el tema ?

Comment: Puedes ver más en el siguiente link: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common)

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir los settings del dispositivo usa el `Intent`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

si lo deseas abrir este un botón

```
btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
```